# Print reports from ArcGIS Enterprise web apps

Tags: arcgis-online, printing, arcgis-web-appbuilder, arcgis-enterprise, print-templates

Can I get my output report in word by publishing a new print service with ArcGIS Web AppBuilder printing tool? The source link I referenced while working on this topic is attached.

https://www.esri.com/arcgis-blog/products/arcgis-enterprise/mapping/print-reports-from-arcgis-enterprise-web-apps/

Answer (score 1):

Can you create a report and return it as a Word document (.doc or docx)? **Yes.**

Is it "simple" *Not really*.

The reporting service you reference will output a PDF or image formats (JPEG, PNG, etc). The workflow described in the blog you reference does not have ability to choose "Word document" and have it create a `.doc` file. You would need to mostly write your own Python code to output a "word - report". The first step would be finding a Python package that can save to `doc`. From there, write the code, and then publish the tool to your Server, ensuring the Server has this Python package installed as well. If you design the service properly you could have it plug into the Web AppBuilder's print service widget. Your service would have to act exactly like a default print service. If it doesn't, you'll need to create your own widget to consume the "report service".

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I wonder if there is a sample work for python code? Unfortunately, as far as I researched, I could not find it.

Comment: As I said, no, it is not simple. You need to find a Python package to create Word documents.